# Client-side validation using bootstrap on asp.net webform - Page.IsValid

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I have an ASP.NET webform using bootstrap and bootstrap validator. The client-side validation seems to be working, but the error message isn't displayed when the btn_click event handler is called. Instead the Catch response is rendered HTML on the page.

I'm fairly new to ASP.NET and I know very little to no VB. Help appreciated.

ASPX:

```
<div class="form-group has-feedback">
<label class="control-label col-sm-6" for="ProxSearcb">Records</label>
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <asp:TextBox ID="ProxSearch" Runat="Server" 
        CausesValidation="true" 
        CssClass="form-control col-sm-6" 
        TextMode="SingleLine" 
        Text="5" 
        ToolTip="Enter the number of records"
        AutoPostBack="false"
        data-bv-notempty="true"
        data-bv-notempty-message="The number of records is required and cannot be empty" >
    </asp:TextBox>
    <asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator2" runat="server" 
        ControlToValidate="ProxSearch" 
        Operator="DataTypeCheck" 
        Type="Integer" 
        EnableClientScript="True" 
        Display="Dynamic" 
        ErrorMessage="Number of records must be a whole number" 
        ValidationGroup="InvCalcGroup">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove red form-control-feedback"></span>
    </asp:CompareValidator>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfdProxSearch" runat="server" 
        ControlToValidate="ProxSearch" 
        Display="Dynamic" 
        EnableClientScript="True" 
        ErrorMessage="Number of records is required" 
        ValidationGroup="InvCalcGroup">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove red form-control-feedback"></span>
    </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <asp:RangeValidator ID="rngProxSearch" runat="server" 
        ControlToValidate="ProxSearch" 
        Display="Dynamic"
        MinimumValue="1"
        MaximumValue="10"
        Type="Integer" 
        EnableClientScript="True" 
        ErrorMessage="Number of records must be between 1 and 10" 
        ValidationGroup="InvCalcGroup">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove red form-control-feedback"></span>
    </asp:RangeValidator>
</div>
</div>
```

VB:

```
Partial Class ...
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
Public Shared anSqlStmt As String

Protected Sub btnSearch_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click

    'adsShowingQuery defined on the web page
    'The DataFile attribute must be set on the web page for sorting and paging to work.

    If Not Page.IsValid Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim KeyNames(0) As String
    KeyNames(0) = "propno"

    adsShowingQuery.SelectCommand = "SELECT TOP " & ProxSearch.Text
    adsShowingQuery.SelectCommand &= " propno, street, city, state, zip, nobdrms, nobathrms, sqft, garagesize, mtnview, pool, askprice, "
    adsShowingQuery.SelectCommand &= "Round(sqr("

    If maxAskPrice.Text <> "" Then
        adsShowingQuery.SelectCommand &= "(((askprice - " & maxAskPrice.Text & ")/1000000)^2) + "
    End If

    If minNoBdrms.Text <> "" Then
        adsShowingQuery.SelectCommand &= "(((nobdrms - " & minNoBdrms.Text & ")/6)^2) + "
    End If

    If minNoBathrms.Text <> "" Then
        adsShowingQuery.SelectCommand &= "(((nobathrms - " & minNoBathrms.Text & ")/5)^2) + "
    End If

    If minSQFT.Text <> "" Then
        adsShowingQuery.SelectCommand &= "(((sqft - " & minSQFT.Text & ")/6000)^2) + "
    End If

    If minGarSize.Text <> "" Then
        adsShowingQuery.SelectCommand &= "(((garagesize - " & minGarSize.Text & ")/4)^2) + "
    End If

    adsShowingQuery.SelectCommand &= "iif(pool = " & hasPool.Checked.ToString() & ", 0,1) + iif(mtnview = " & hasMtnView.Checked.ToString() & ", 0,1)"
    adsShowingQuery.SelectCommand &= "),4) AS distance FROM Property ORDER BY 13"

    gvShowing.DataKeyNames = KeyNames
    gvShowing.AllowPaging = True
    gvShowing.AllowSorting = True
    gvShowing.Visible = True
    gvShowing.DataSourceID = "adsShowingQuery"
    gvShowing.AutoGenerateColumns = True

    anSqlStmt = adsShowingQuery.SelectCommand

    Try
        gvShowing.DataBind()

    Catch ex As Exception
        Response.Write("Exception in btnSearch_Click when binding to grid <br />")
        Response.Write("Access Exception Handler: {0}  " & ex.ToString() & "<br />")
        Response.Write("SQL statement = " & anSqlStmt)
    End Try

End Sub

Protected Sub gvShowing_PageIndexChanging(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewPageEventArgs) Handles gvShowing.PageIndexChanging
    'The DataFile attribute must be set on the web page for sorting and paging to work.
    adsShowingQuery.SelectCommand = anSqlStmt
End Sub

Protected Sub gvShowing_Sorting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewSortEventArgs) Handles gvShowing.Sorting
    'The DataFile attribute must be set on the web page for sorting and paging to work.
    adsShowingQuery.SelectCommand = anSqlStmt
End Sub

End Class
```